# App Settings to reference ADO Library via Variable Substitution. XML App.Config

Tags: c#, xml, selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, vstest

Is there a method of swapping the AppSettings on the XML on the app.config file, so that it gets the settings from the variables.

This is for a VSTEST 2019, EasyRepo, UI Test.

I have a bunch of sensitive settings on my app.config which i want to hide, and reference via my Azure Library.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
        <appSettings>
            <add key="OnlineUsername" value="MyUserName" />
            <add key="OnlinePassword" value="myPassword" />
            <add key="OnlineCrmUrl" value="www.url.com" />
            <add key="MfaSecretKey" value="" />
            <add key="AzureKey" value="" />
etc...
```

I have attempted a file-transform task, and set the library for the reference of my App.Config file to be transformed. I also put the variables on the YAML it self, but did not work.

Is there a method of swapping the AppSettings on the XML on the app.config file, so that it gets the settings from the variables.